# how can I structure amp-analytics json iframeMessage with dynamic values?

Tags: json, amp-html, adobe-analytics, amp-analytics

I am trying to integrate adobe analytics in an amp page. But the parameters that I want to pass, I want them to be picked up dynamically using an ajax call. 
I am picking up the values using an amp-list. The ajax response is somewhat like below:

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "user_type": "site_user",
      "user_id": "anonymous"
    }
  ]
}
```

In the amp-analytics section I am trying to read the dynamic values of user_type and user_id using curly braces syntax. My code snippet looks like this:

```
<amp-analytics type="adobeanalytics_nativeConfig">
    <script type="application/json">
    {
        "requests": {
            "base": "${base}",
            "iframeMessage": "${base}/stats.html?user_type={{user_type}}&user_id={{user_id}}"
        },
        "vars": {
            "host": "${host}"
        }
    }
    </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

But instead of getting the values in the stats.html iframe request, the same syntax with curly braces itself is getting passes as values in the query parameters. This is what I am getting when the amp-analytics tag is defined outside the amp-list block. 
When I am putting the entire amp-analytics block within amp-list block, I do not see the stats.html call getting triggered. In browser console I am getting the below error:

> No request strings defined. Analytics data will not be sent from this
>   page. Ignoring event. Request string not found:  iframeMessage

Both `base` and `host` are jstl variables and they are getting replaced with their proper values.

Can anyone please help on passing the dynamic values to structure the json iframe?

Comment: did you find the solution to it?

Comment: @rajat44: please refer to the [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61809416/6381711) below.

Answer (score 0):

For your Adobe Analytics AMP HTML integration, use the snippet below to pass your `user_id` and `user_type` variables to your `stats.html` page;

```html
<amp-analytics type="adobeanalytics_nativeConfig">
  <script type="application/json">
    {
      "requests": {
        "base": "https://${host}",
        "iframeMessage": "${base}/stats.html?user_id=${user_id}&user_type=${user_type}"
      },
      "vars": {
        "host": "analytics.example.com",
        "user_id": "anonymous",
        "user_type": "site_user"
      }
    }
  </script>
</amp-analytics>
```

The interpolated `${base}` variable will resolve into the base your defined `host` variable.

The `host` variable must be defined as a domain name other than the one serving your AMP HTML page; that's where your `stats.html` page must be hosted (as shared in the snippet, stats.html is located at the root of `analytics.example.com` the analytics domain name).

Your custom variables, just as your `host` variable, equally needs to be defined as under the `vars` object as illustrated above.